# Is a field tip as effective as a hunting tip for small game

Tags: gear, hunting, bow-hunting

Note: *This question is asked in an absolutely theoretical manner.* ***NEVER hunt without proper equipment!***

I often ask myself what probably would happen if I shoot small game with a field tip attached. I often feel like it would kill it just like a hunting tip (not talking about blunts etc.) would do, wouldn't it?

And if yes, which would be the size too big to kill with a field tip?

Comment: as I note, I shot a rabbit with my target arrow once. The arrows passed through and hit the bank behind and the rabbit ran away. Probably died if I had a crit hit but I guess I will never know. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chances are you'll be doing a lot more tracking. Blunt tips are for very small game, intended to knock they prey out cold or cause death by blunt trauma.

Hunting tips are intended to increase depth of penetration as well as doing continuous damage to the vital organs once full penetration has occurred.

Hunting tips will almost always penetrate deeper than field tips in flesh, because the razor cut a cross around the puncture, this reduces the tension of the wound around the shaft. In other words, A field tip will stop faster because the flesh will be grabbing it better.

Can you use field tips to hunt? Sure, but you will likely be forced to track for longer, the arrow may fall out of the wound when the animal is running through brush, and may be able to find a spot to hide and die (or heal) and you may never find it.

Answer (score 5):

The outcome in the use of the set up you speak of, will also greatly depend on the size of the game you are considering hunting. On small game a field tip will penetrate, and in most instances, pin the game to the ground unless shooting at extreme angles. While this would work to harvest a smaller animal, I would definitely not recommend it on any size game. With smaller game, a harvest would be an almost given however, the results may be a lengthy death for the game animal which wouldn't be the most ethical hunting practice.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add something to the very good existing answers.

> While this would work to harvest a smaller animal, I would definitely
>   not recommend it on any size game. With smaller game, a harvest would
>   be an almost given however, the results may be a lengthy death for the
>   game animal which wouldn't be the most ethical hunting practice.

From [user8199](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/8199/user8199)'s [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/9962/8060)

---

I've found a awesome resource which handles this topic pretty nicely.

> [image: Slice]
>
> ### Broadhead Vs Field Tip Arrows
>
> A common misconception amongst non bow hunters is that the arrow has a
>   thin pointy tip, also known as a "field tip". These are used for
>   target shooting and NOTHING else regardless of what you might have
>   seen or read in the news or on TV.
>
> A field tip is from a hunting point of view useless, it only inflicts
>   pain but does not really kill any animals. The broad heads used for
>   hunting on the other hand uses 2-4 razor sharp blades that slices
>   artery's and vain's like a surgeons scalpel, which in turn renders a
>   massive hemmorhage and the blood loss kills the animal within minutes
>   after impact.

From [Europeanbowhunting.org](http://www.europeanbowhunting.org/index.php/studies/broadhead-vs-feild-tip)

Further reading:

- https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060914132541AAafdSE
- https://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100818110020AAOJj3M