# What's a bullet tip/point?

Tags: gear, archery

Someone has recently mentioned a "bullet tip". I assume he meant something for target shooting but it sounds like some hunting equipment.

So, what exactly did he refer to?

Comment: I have to ask, because initially thought you were asking questions as an honest beginner but I am sure that's not the case, so what's your purpose? It seems you are now writing questions and answers offline, then just adding both at once.

Comment: @Escoce Checkin: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp I'll explain it there.

Comment: Ima there and said hello :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, a "bullet tip" or "point" is something used for target shooting. In fact, it's THE arrowhead used for target shooting.

The term "bullet" refers to its shape:

[image: Bullet point]

However, the bullet point and the field tip are the most used arrowheads for target shooting.

Here's a listing of the most common points (classical broadhead is missing):

[image: List]

*I wanted to make clear that you never ever should use a bullet point to hunt!* As you've already assumed the point is only used for sports. Read more about [this topic here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/is-a-field-tip-as-effective-as-a-hunting-tip-for-small-game).

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining *why* one should not use a bullet point to hunt. I don't know anything about archery, and I can't figure out why from your answer and I don't know where to look to find more information.

Comment: @GregHewgill Nice input! Thanks :) I've edited the question and linked to another question about this topic.